# Authlogic RPX extended permissions

Tags: facebook, authlogic, rpxnow, rpx

I am working on the Facebook Connect feature for a Ruby on Rails website. I noticed that FB doesn't provide the user's email unless you demand extended permissions. I'm using the authlogic_rpx gem.

Does anyone know, if it's possible, and if how, to ask the user for granting access to his email address using the authlogic_rpx gem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Please, follow instructions given on
http://github.com/tardate/authlogic_rpx .
There you can find how to enable the mapping!